# Recreating Memory Situation From gc.log / replay gc.log

Tags: performance, garbage-collection, performance-testing, simulate

I was wondering if anyone knows a tool recreating a memory situation / memory load from an existing gc log to test different gc settings. 
With enough print parameters switched on it should be possible to create a similar load situation based on the collection times and the amount of surviving / collected data.

Does anyone know such a tool ?

Answer (score 0):

You can not replay gc.log itself because it doesn't contain information about what kind of objects caused memory collection. If I were you, I'd have tried to recreate a realistic workload on your app and monitored how it worked. Then maybe 2x and 3x... loads to see how it scales.
Which kind of app do you have? Is it a web server or a desktop application?

P.S. You could use [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) to see how GC works. There are also a couple of profiling tools there.

Comment: Sorry i somehow missed that someone responded to this old thread nevertheless i think the topic is still interesting. I did not have time to advance in this direction. I was thinking to recreate arbitrary objects to repeat the load situation by using the tenuring distribution statistics to recreate a similar load. Its a desktop application.